# Kivy - Urlrequest works on my computer but not on my phone

Tags: python, kivy

I have made a simple app that uses urlrequest and the Wikimedia api to get some information from Wikipedia. While this perfectly works on my computer (it shows the information), it does not on my phone (it shows nothing).

The main script:

```
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class WikiApp(App):
   summary = StringProperty()

   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(**kwargs)
       self.summary = ""

   def results(self, req, result):
       self.summary = str(result["query"]['searchinfo']['totalhits'])

   def build(self):
       return MainScreen()

   def generate(self):
       req = UrlRequest('https://en.wikipedia.org//w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=abc', self.results)

class MainScreen(BoxLayout):
   """Class for the main screen widget"""
   pass
```

and the kv file:

```
<MainScreen>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: SummaryLabel
            text: app.summary
            size_hint_y: None
            text_size: self.width, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            id: generate
            text: "Generate"
            on_release: app.generate()
```

Why is it not working on my phone ? Is there something I need to specify in the spec file ?
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `import certifi` then add another parameter to your `UrlRequest` function -- `ca_file=certifi.where()`

For Example:
`req = UrlRequest('https://en.wikipedia.org//w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=abc', self.results, ca_file=certifi.where())`

Comment: It works now. Thank you ! Just in case, after modifying the code, the app crashed on my phone due to `06-15 08:52:08.007 12677 12710 I python  :  ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists`. I had to make req an instance attribute and the problem disappeared.

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer since it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should put `INTERNET` permission in the `buildozer.spec` file:

```
android.permissions = INTERNET
```

And after launch of the app, manually give the permission for internet going to the app info. If you want the app to prompt for the permission then you need to implement `request_permissions`, `check_permission` methods in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already have `android.permissions = INTERNET` in my spec file but how do I give the permission for internet in my code ? Also what module do I need for `request_permissions` and `check_permission` ?

Comment: Just to understand more first, after you install the app have you manually given the INTERNET permission going to the app info?

Comment: How does one manually add request_permssions and check_permissions? And I don't have the ability to set the internet permssion in App Info?